# why is msi installer created using windows installer xml i.e wix only?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I am in serious doubt that why cant we use any language other than wix to create msi installer .
Using the following setup features :
windows installer 3.1
WIX toolset

Comment: You are correct in that WiX provides a _textual, declarative language_ to specify a Windows Installer package. Windows Installer does have a [procedural language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021(v=vs.85).aspx) that is primarily used by tools. There are other tools to build Windows Installer packages but I don't know of any that have a language (at least not a textual one).

Answer (score 4):

Windows Installer is a Windows platform service that consists of a client, service, API, database specification and SDK.

The primary database types are .MSI (installer), .MSM (merge module), .MSP (patch), .MST (transform), .CUB (unit tests) .PCP (patch source code) and maybe more I've forgotten.

Windows Installer XML is an XML / XSD language and compiler  that transforms the XML into Windows Installer databases.

There are other tools available that create Windows Installer databases.  The 800lb Gorilla of which is InstallShield.  A comprehensive list can be found at:

[Windows Installer Authoring Tools for Developers](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm)